# Allow one way SSH on extended IP access list on Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, acl

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
 ip access-group VM01-BLOCK-SSH-ACCESS-OUT out
```

objective:

```
10.10.10.104 -x-> any 10.10.10.0/24 via SSH
any 10.10.10.0/24 via SSH  ---> 10.10.10.104
```

Question: how could I set M01-BLOCK-SSH-ACCESS-OUT for my objective?

Comment: Traffic in the same network does not pass through a router, so the router ACL will not work. That is something you need to configure on the hosts because on the same network, traffic is sent directly from host to host, not through a router.

Comment: @RonMaupin The OP is asking about a Cisco *switch*... ;-)

Comment: Yes, but that is a layer-3 ACL, so it is for a routing module in a layer-3 switch, or a router.